# How to write multi time frame code in Pine Editor?

Tags: pine-script

I want to write a code wherein the Buy condition is

If Daily 3ema > daily 7ema
Then Go long when hourly 3ema crosses over hourly 7ema.

How to apply Multi timeframe in Pine Editor?

Comment: Please include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

These are good places to start exploring MTF features in Pine. You're in luck; they are relatively easy to use:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html
https://www.tradingview.com/script/90mqACUV-MTF-Selection-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/
https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/